# Rails Backbone Marionette Assets No Longer Updating When Changed?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, marionette

Something weird started happening to me today - when changing the HTML/CSS of my Backbone Marionette Rails app the changes no longer seem to be propagating in my app. It seems like there's some sort of weird caching going on. Has anyone run into this before? If I `rake assets:clean` it doesn't seem to update the javascript changes, just the css.

Does anyone know how to force the assets to be reloaded on each GET request in development?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
I'd also point out that I've tried re-starting my server and restarting my computer but the changes still don't seem to propagate. Example, in my CSS folder I changed the padding from `padding: 20px 10px 20px 10px;` to `20px 0px 20px 0px`

```
#free-text-answer {
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 10px 20px 20px 20px;
    background: #EEE;
    border: 1px dashed #DDD;
    padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #666;
}
```

but inspecting the element it still shows `padding: 20px 10px 20px 10px;`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I finally fixed it. I deleted the public/assets folder and set this in my development.rb file:

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```